# How to replicate local code to Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ide

I am hosting a web application in ubuntu using nodejs. i am using Webstorm ide and when ever i add some update then i have to connect to the server using ssh and copy and past the new code. isn't there any IDE available which do this automatically. at least it should has a button with credential to the server so when ever new update is ready to publish press the button and update the code on the server.

Comment: Use git to version your code and then use it to deploy your code whenever you want

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this. I would use Docker my self, as it is very useful during development as well, and it is portable. You can use node-ansible and many many more. Which is the best for node in particular I don’t know. But search for deploy systems and you will definitely find.